# More elegant way of expressing Lagrange polynomial.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

On wikipedia the Lagrange polynomial looks messy, I think I found a elegant way to express the Lagrange polynomial:

Like this (where $\Delta L(x)$ represents $L(x+1)-L(x)$:

$$L(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\Delta^i (0)) \binom{x}{i}$$

> Question 
>   Is this correct and where can I read about this?

For example:

Find the Lagrange polynomial for:

$$0,1,4,9,16,25,...$$

Taking the differences.Take note of the first term of the sequences (subscript 0):

$$1,3,5,7,9,...$$

$$2,2,2,2,...$$

$$0,0,0,..$$

$$0,0,..$$

$$0,...$$

$$0,...$$

....

Note the initial terms of the above sequences is $0,1,2,0,0,0,0..$.

So we have:

$$L(x)=0{x \choose 0}+1{x \choose 1}+2{x \choose 2}+0{x \choose 3}+0{x \choose 4}+0{x \choose 5}+0{x \choose 6}...=x^2$$

Comment: This isn't as general as the Lagrange polynomial.  You are assuming that the sample points are $0,1,\ldots,x$.  And why is $x$ both a limit of summation and a polynomial input?

Comment: Essentially, this is the [umbral Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus#Umbral_Taylor_series).  For a more general form, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial.

Comment: I've edited it @ErickWong

Comment: But now your sum uses the same iterate of $\Delta$ for every term of the summation :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Erick Wong notes:

> This isn't as general as the Lagrange polynomial. [The OP is] assuming that the sample points are $0,1,…,x$

Meaning, this formula will not work for interpolating points like $(0,1)$, $(4,5)$, $(7,8)$. It will only work with points following $(0,L(0)),(1,L(1)),(2,L(2)),...$.

However this is an elegant way to express a Lagrange polynomial for a sequence, if we take the first term to be $L(0)$, the second to be $L(1)$, and so on.

> @Erick Wong also notes that the given formula is essentially another way to express the umbral Taylor series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus#Umbral_Taylor_series